# How can I show the up/down arrows(carrots) on select element

Tags: css

In our old version there's a up/down carrots on the select element.
However, I inspect the element and css.
There's no place defining the carrots style.

I want to show the carrots on our new version.
How could I do that using css.

I believe I need the `after` selector.

```
select:after {
}
```

## Old version

[image: inline]

## new version

[image: inline]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the `appearance` property. It's used to display the element in a platform-native manner. Meaning that you let the browser apply the default style for it. Make sure you don't have `appearance: none` anywhere.

You can manually set it, but it should be set by default. For `select` the value is `menulist`:

`-webkit-appearance: menulist;
-moz-appearance:    menulist;
appearance:         menulist;`

Comment: not working as well. even I add this css attribute on the select element https://i.imgur.com/4ja9l2F.png

Comment: @newBike You should post the entire css styles that apply to the element. Maybe do a JSFiddle and link it here?

Comment: my bad, there attrs were overwriten by some attrs